# How do I view message context in Lokalize immediately in a pane?

Tags: perl, gettext

[context in the application Lokalize http://www3.pic-upload.de/24.06.10/ycpxjk6ikvxz.png](http://www3.pic-upload.de/24.06.10/ycpxjk6ikvxz.png)

All I see is just the file name and line number, as highlighted in the screenshot above. Activating the link shows a dialog box with the information: »Cannot open source files: no scripts to do so are currently loaded. Refer to the [Lokalize handbook](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdesdk/lokalize/scripting.html) for script examples and how to plug them into your project.«

However, after reading this, I'm as smart as before - this software's design is downright hostile. Exactly what do I have to copy where to make this work?

Alternatively, recommend a PO editor that is confirmed to have this feature I need. [PO files for testing](http://github.com/jquelin/games-risk) are available.

Comment: Is this even programming related?

Comment: Yes, see [FAQ §1](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#What%20kind%20of%20questions%20can%20I%20ask%20here%3F) about software tools.

Comment: What KDE Version is this? What distro/release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's overcomplicated, but the opensrc.* files in /usr/share/kde4/apps/lokalize/scripts/ or http://websvn.kde.org/trunk/l10n-kde4/scripts/lokalize/ should get you started. The .rc file can be installed by dragging it to Project->Configure->Scripts.